# Exporting Linear Regression Results Including Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, export, regression, linear-regression

Hey out there how can I can I export a table of the results used to make the chart I generated for this linear regression model below.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(200110,86933,104429,240752,255332,75998,
                    204302,97321,342812,220522,110990,259706,65733),
                y=c(200000,110000,165363,225362,313284,113972,
                    137449,113106,409020,261733,171300,344437,89000))

lm1 <- lm(y~x,data=d)

p_conf1 <- predict(lm1,interval="confidence")


nd <- data.frame(x=seq(0,80000,length=510000))
p_conf2 <- predict(lm1,interval="confidence",newdata=nd)



plot(y~x,data=d,ylim=c(-21750,600000),xlim=c(0,600000)) ## data
abline(lm1) ## fit
matlines(d$x,p_conf1[,c("lwr","upr")],col=2,lty=1,type="b",pch="+")

matlines(nd$x,p_conf2[,c("lwr","upr")],col=4,lty=1,type="b",pch="+")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want in the table?

Comment: A couple of small points: (1) do you really need the prediction evaluated for 510000 values between 0 and 80000?  Seems like overkill (at least for graphical output) ... (2) your picture will be prettier if you sort `d` by `x`: `d <- d[order(d$x),]`, otherwise your first `matlines` output has crossing lines.  The *general* answer to your question is `write.csv(data.frame(...))`, but details await your answer to @MattParker's comment ...

Comment: Thanks I certainly can narrow the prediction margin. Typo I think. My goals are to generate a chart showing how confidence intervals change with this model as we move beyond the lower bounds of the data used to generate the linear regression. In addition I would like to be able to generate a confidence interval for any predicted y within or outside the data set. Then have access to those results.

Comment: By the way, if your question has been answered satisfactorily it's considered good form (but not strictly *required*) to click on the check mark next to the best answer to accept it ...

Answer (score 1):

Still not entirely sure what you want but this would seem to be reasonable:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(d,p_conf1)
dat2 <- data.frame(nd,y=NA,p_conf2)
write.csv(rbind(dat1,dat2),file="linpredout.csv")
```

It includes `x`, `y` (equal to the observation or `NA` for non-observed points), the predicted value `fit`, and `lwr`/`upr` bounds.

**edit**: fix typo.

Comment: Blolker Hey thanks so much for this help. I am totally green with this program and the language. It took me hours with the manual to get this far. I am so close but as you can see below the code generated an error I am sure on my part for improper use. I just stuck it at the end of what I had already written. thoughts?...
> 
> dat1 <- data.frame(d,p_conf1)
> dat2 <- data.frame(nd,y=NA,p_conf2)
> write.csv(rbind(dat1,tdat2),file="linpredout.csv")
Error in rbind(dat1, tdat2) : object 'tdat2' not found

Comment: @Bolker Cool it does not generate error message now-- but I must not be using it in the right location within my code as no .csv file is being generated. Or if it is I do not know where to find it. Really am appreciating you help with this.

Comment: `?getwd` (which explains both getting and setting the working directory). Or use an absolute path, e.g. `file="c:/myout.csv"` -- but it's *much* better in the long run to understand how working directories work.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a matrix that has some of the information needed to construct the confidence intervals:

```
> coef(summary(lm1))
                Estimate   Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 21749.037058 2.665203e+04 0.8160369 4.317954e-01
x               1.046954 1.374353e-01 7.6177997 1.037175e-05
```

Any text on linear regression should have the formula for the confidence interval. You may need to calculate some ancillary quantities dependent on which formula you're using. The code for predict is visible ... just type at the console :

```
predict.lm
```

And don't forget that confidence intervals are different than prediction intervals.

Comment: I think if the OP wanted to be able to predict intervals outside of R they'd need the results of `vcov()` too (i.e. slope-intercept correlation) ... but that's not how I read their question.

Comment: I guess we did read it differently. I thought the OP wanted to construct a formula for the CI bands.